# How to detect ftp server timeouts in Python

Tags: python

Uploading large amounts of files to an FTP server. In the middle of my upload the server times out preventing me from uploading any further. Does anyone know of a way to detect if the server has timed out, reconnect and continue transmission of the data? I am using the Python ftp library for the transmission.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of response do you get (if any)?  Is it [one of the 400 codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes)?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply specify a timeout for the connect, but for timeouts during file transfer or other operations it's not so simple.

Because the storbinary and retrbinary methods allow you to provide a callback, you can implement a watchdog timer.  Each time you get data you reset the timer.  If you don't get data at least every 30 seconds (or whatever) the watchdog will attempt to abort and close the FTP session and send an event back to your event loop (or whatever).

```
ftpc = FTP(myhost, 'ftp', 30)

def timeout():
  ftpc.abort()  # may not work according to docs
  ftpc.close()
  eventq.put('Abort event')  # or whatever

timerthread = [threading.Timer(30, timeout)]

def callback(data, *args, **kwargs):
  eventq.put(('Got data', data))  # or whatever
  if timerthread[0] is not None:
    timerthread[0].cancel()
  timerthread[0] = threading.Timer(30, timeout)
  timerthread[0].start()

timerthread[0].start()
ftpc.retrbinary('RETR %s' % (somefile,), callback)
timerthread[0].cancel()
```

If this isn't good enough, it appears you will have to choose a different API.  The Twisted framework has [FTP protocol support](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.protocols.ftp.html) that should allow you to add timeout logic.